# Schema hasn't been registered for model in Schema but not others from the same source

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to populate a node express route with information from Schemas, and I keep getting this error.  What I cannot understand is that I am referencing three different fields in the same exact Schema and for some reason, I am only getting this error for one of those fields.

This is my route function where I am getting "MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "completed_by_user""

```
// Schemas
const Transaction = require ("../models/transaction");
User              = require ("../models/user");
Ticket            = require ("../models/ticket");
Job               = require ("../models/job");
Client            = require ("../models/client");

// Functions
let numberWithCommas = require("../functions/numberWithCommas");

module.exports = function(app) {

    // =======================Tickets

// index
app.get("/tickets", function(req, res){
    Ticket.find({}).populate("created_by", "assigned_user", "completed_by_user").exec(function(err, tickets){  //This is where it happens
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.render("tickets", {tickets: tickets});
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the Ticket Schema itself:

```
const Transaction = require ("./transaction");
User              = require ("./user");
Ticket            = require ("./ticket");
Job               = require ("./job");
Client            = require ("./client");

// =======================Ticket Schema

var ticketSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ticket_name: String,
    description: String,
    created_by: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: "User"}],
    assigned_user: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: "User"}],
    completed_by_user: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: "User"}],
    due_date: {type: Date},
    completed_date: {type: Date},
    completed_description: String,
    date_added: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Ticket", ticketSchema);
```

I am not getting this error for "created_by" or for "assigned_user" but I am getting it for "completed_by_user."  I don't understand why this would be since they are all populated in the same Schema.  This is not the only occurrence of this type of issue I am having, but I am sure it is for the same reason.  I even tried changing the order I require the schemas and that has not helped either.  Is there something obvious I am missing?  Thanks.

Comment: That's not the right syntax for populating multiple fields. Referring to the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_an_existing_mongoose_document) you can use the following `.populate("created_by").populate("assigned_user").populate("completed_by_user")`

Comment: Thank you so much, I cannot recall where I learned to populate multiple fields, but obviously what I learned was wrong.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
.populate(["created_by", "assigned_user", "completed_by_user"])
```

Try this because .populate function takes only one argument by putting it into array it takes multiple